# Microservices with spring boot, WITHOUT spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I am new in Microservice. Can we implement a microservice with the help of spring boot, without spring cloud. In every tutorial it has been mentioned as create Microservice using spring boot and spring cloud. Kindly elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here's a pretty much simplest possible spring boot microservice:

```
@RestController
class HelloworldController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  String home() {
    return "Hello world!"
  }
}
```

which you can save into Helloworld.groovy and run with `spring run Helloworld.groovy`, assuming you have [spring boot cli installed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html#getting-started-installing-the-cli).

Comment: But isn't it an example of spring rest? I am trying to use maven, not much a good understanding about groovy

Comment: @Shubha do you think service using rest isn't a microservice?

Comment: As microservice is an architecture, and using spring rest we can achieve them, I agree. As i have already said,I am new to it, with your example I can relate it to spring rest. Is there any other possible ways to develop?

Comment: @Shubha there are lots and lots of ways to develop things. a microservice is an architectural pattern, it does not imply anything about the way it is developed

Answer (score 2):

Definitely yes.

Microservice architecture doesn't necessarily assume that a microservice will run in a cloud environment.

Spring cloud provides "extra" features usually required in cloud environments, for instance centralized configuration management, service discovery, etc.

So using spring boot allows running microservice (strictly speaking you can even have spring boot driven monoliths) but without all the aforementioned features for cloud.

Comment: Thanks Mark, for your answer. Is there any good tutorial for that you suggest